# Java create custom validation annotation like @NotNull for method parameters

Tags: java, validation, annotations

This is Hibernate validation **NOT SPRING**

I want to create an annotation such as `@Approved` that I can use in a method to validate arguments.

For example:

```
public class SomeClass implements Approvable {
  @Override
  public boolean isApproved(){
    return false;
  }
}
```

My @Approved annotation would validate the class by returning the `isApprovced()` result.

Then, when I have a method like:

`public void sendMessage(@Approved SomeClass someClass){ ... }`

I would get an error just like if I had a `@Valid` annotation on a bean that was not valid (i.e. had a null value in a `@NotNull` field).

I can create an annotation and a `ConstraintValidator<Approved, Approvable>` but that only works with `@Valid`.  How do I do this with method parameters and custom annotations?  I can't find an example.